# @angular/router wrap route component in router-outlet for styling

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-animations

I have a simple angular *(8+)* application using `@angular/router` with multiple components as routes, and each component use `@angular/animations` for transitions.

`<router-outlet>` directive is fullscreen using css `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh` to override default scroll. My idea is to wrap each route with a  `<div>` or a specific class which will allow to define fixed layout.

My current version works great, **but I have to manually add the `<div>` and was hoping to find an automatic solution** like `@angular/animations` does.

### app.ts with main router

```
  <main [@routerTransition]="getState(o)">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
  </main>
```

### Route component html template

```
<div class="route"> <!--  class which should be automatically wrapped -->
  <div class="container">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Blablabla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Routes

```
// State is use to bind animation
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'page1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page1/page1.module').then(mod => mod.Page1Module),
    data: { theme: 'light' }
  },
  {
    path: 'page2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page2/page2.module').then(mod => mod.Page2Module),
    data: { theme: 'light' }
  },
  ...
];
```

Like I said, **this code works** exactly as expectied, but having to maintain manually a certain DOM layout is not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Content projection will do the job. Basically you have a shell/wrapper component. And all your individual route component will project their content into this shell/wrapper.

RouteShellComponent:

```
<div class="route">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

RouteAComponent:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

main

```
<app-route-shell>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-route-shell>
```

Comment: It seams like this will generate something like `<div class="route"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>` ... from my understanding  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` add pages as Sibling the itself so I would need `<router-outlet></router-outlet><div class="route"><!--RouteAComponent--></ng-content></div>`. Might be confuse about **Content projection** may be ...

Comment: The position doesn't really matter. <router-outlet> is only an anchor element which doesn't impact the html structure.

Comment: When inspecting my dom, I can see all routes are display after <router-outlet>, so if I have two routes doing a transition, I will have in my DOM: `<app-route-shell>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>< Route 1/><Route 2/></app-route-shell>`. What I need it `<app-route-shell>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet><div class="Route">< Route 1/></div><div class="Route"><Route 2/></div></app-route-shell>` . Sorry, my question was maybe not very clean.

Comment: If that is the case I would tend to make the `<div class="route">` a route, and in turn it routes to each individual component with the title. This is not a great idea tho. lol.